# Eclipse RCP Completion Proposal Doesn't Respect Replacement Length

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, content-assist

While applying a CompletionProposal in a JFace text editor, the replacementLength argument in the proposal seems to not be respected.

Here's the proposal I add:

```
CompletionProposal comp = new CompletionProposal(replacementStr,
   replacementOffset, replacementLength, cursorPosition , img,     
   displayStr, null, additionalInfoStr);
```

The replacement offset and length and string values are verified in the debugger to be just what I expect. When the proposal is applied it is inserted at the caret offset as expected, but it does not replace any of the text on the line. Instead, the text to the right of the caret is shifted to the right of the inserted text. The replacement length corresponds to the length of text highlighted, but it doesn't work without any selection either, in which case I hard-code the expected replacement length.

I didn't find any reports of this problem while searching, and the JDT editor replaces text as expected when I apply a propsal with some text selected. So I assume there's something else needed, as the API is pretty straightforward and I don't see the expected result.

Comment: This works fine testing in my code.

Comment: Seeing as @greg-449 finds it works I have not tried it myself. Can you confirm the context of the replacement? Is it perhaps different in the PyDev editor than JDT one?

Comment: It only breaks for me in PyDev. I'd like to know if you can reproduce what I'm seeing. Using the PyDev proposals, not my custom proposals, I find the replacement does not work properly. I see from the code that you have to hold the Ctrl button down when you apply the proposal, to make the "eat" parameter true when calling PyLinkedModeCompletionProposal#applyOnDoc. But then fLen is 0, which causes no text to be replaced. fLen is never set in AstractCompletionProposalExtension#selected because it is always called with smartTogge false. I don't know if something in my code causes that or not.

Comment: Even with smartToggle forced to true, fLen is 0 because I select the function name or the entire function call with args, and fLen measures the distance to the first "(" or the end of the line. I don't understand the intent here (and applyOnDoc also truncates the replacement text to just the function name). I'm trying to replace an entire function call, and PyDev proposals and my custom proposals return a function call with args. So I don't understand why the replace is being limited to function names here. If you replace a function name with another, the args are likely to be different.